# python-requests post with unicode filenames

Tags: python, unicode, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I've read through several related questions here on SO but didn't manage to find a working solution.

I have a Flask server with this simplified code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class SendMailAPI(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print request.files
        return Response(status=200)

api.add_resource(SendMailAPI, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Then in the client:

```
# coding:utf-8

import requests

eng_file_name = 'a.txt'
heb_file_name = u'א.txt'

requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', files={'file0': open(eng_file_name, 'rb')})
requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', files={'file0': open(heb_file_name, 'rb')})
```

When sending the first request with the non-utf-8 filename the server receives the request with the file and prints `ImmutableMultiDict([('file0', <FileStorage: u'a.txt' (None)>)])`, but when sending the file with the utf-8 filename the server doesn't seem to receive the file as it prints `ImmutableMultiDict([])`.

I'm using requests `2.3.0` but the problem doesn't resolve with the latest version as well (`2.8.1`), Flask version is `0.10.1` and Flask-RESTful version is `0.3.4`.

I've done some digging in `requests` code and the request seems to be sent ok (ie with the file), and I printed the request right before it is being sent and see the file name was indeed encoded to RFC2231:

```
--6ea257530b254861b71626f10a801726
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename*=utf-8''%D7%90.txt
```

To sum things up, I'm not entirely sure if the problem lies within `requests` that doesn't properly attach the file to the request or if `Flask` is having issues with picking up files with file names that are encoded according to RFC2231.

**UPDATE:** Came across this issue in `requests` GitHub: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2505

Comment: Since the request is okay, this must be the server. The question looks like a run-of-the-mill debugging task for me. Add some breakpoints/debug printing here and there to ultmately pinpoint the specific line of code that does it wrong.

Comment: so requests encodes the file names in a way that flask doesn't support?

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe there's confusion here on encoding here -

```
eng_file_name = 'a.txt'  # ASCII encoded, by default in Python 2
heb_file_name = u'א.txt'  # NOT UTF-8 Encoded - just a unicode object
```

To send the second one to the server what you want to do is this:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', files={'file0': open(heb_file_name.encode('utf-8'), 'rb')})
```

I'm a little surprised that it doesn't throw an error on the client trying to open the file though - you see nothing on the client end indicating an error?

EDIT: An easy way to confirm or deny my idea is of course to print out the contents from inside the client to ensure it's being read properly.

Answer (score 1):

I workaround this issue by manually reading the file with `read()` and then posting its contents:

```
requests.post(upload_url, files={
    'file': ("photo.jpg", open(path_with_unicode_filename, 'rb').read())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:
`filename.encode("utf-8").decode("iso-8859-1")`.

Example:

```
requests.post("https://example.com", files={"file":
    ("中文filename.txt".encode("utf-8").decode("iso-8859-1"), fobj, mimetype)})
```

I post this because this is my first result when searching `python requests post filename encoding`.

There are lots of RFC standards about `Content-Disposition` encoding.
And it seems that different programs implement this part differently.

See [stackoverflow: lots of RFCs and application tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http), [RFC 2231 - 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231.html), [email.utils.encode_rfc2231](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.utils.html).

[Java version answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976569/).